# Python AttributeError: class has no attribute

Tags: python, class, attributeerror, simpy

I have this code with a class queue which consist of `simpy` `Resource` and `Container` (`buffer`):

```
class queue:
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.port = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)
        self.buffer = simpy.Container(env, init = 0, capacity=1250000000)
        self.mon_proc = env.process(self.monitor_tank(env))
```

But when I want to use the class and it's attribute buffer using

```
def Packet(env, id, size, port, time_in_port):

    arrive = env.now
    yield queue.buffer.put(size)
    print('packet%s %s arriving at %lf' % (id, size, arrive))

    with port.request() as req:
        yield req

        tip = random.expovariate(1/time_in_port)
        yield env.timeout(tip)
        amount = size
        yield queue.buffer.get(amount)
        print('packet%s %s depart at %lf' % (id, size, env.now))
```

I'm getting the following error when calling queue.buffer

```
AttributeError: class queue has no attribute 'buffer'
```

Mind to explain why I can't use the attribute from the class?
Thanks.

Comment: `buffer` is not the same as `Buffer`.

Comment: @khelwood sorry, i fixed that typo. still facing the same problem

Comment: Do you actually instantiate your queue class somewhere? It looks like you are just trying to use the class directly

Comment: `queue` is a class. `queue()` is an instance of the class. `buffer` is an attribute of an _instance_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `queue` is your class, and it has an instance attribute of `buffer`, then you can access `buffer` through *instances* of your class, not the class itself.

E.g.

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.port = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)
        self.buffer = simpy.Container(env, init = 0, capacity=1250000000)
        self.mon_proc = env.process(self.monitor_tank(env))

def Packet(env, id, size, port, time_in_port):
    queue = Queue(env) # instantiate your class
    ...
    # Make use of queue.buffer
```

Comment: Thanks mate! that fix it.